# for loop working for only first value

Tags: arrays, for-loop

```
var active_dates1 = ["2017-04-02 00:00:00","2014-04-03 00:00:00","2014-04-01 00:00:00"];
$('.datePick', this.$el).datepicker(

    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        for(let date1 of active_dates1){
        if (date.getTime() === new Date(date1).getTime()) {
            return { classes: 'activeClass' };
        }
        else {
            return {};
        }
        }

    }
});
```

code is changing the color of first date value (2017-04-02 00:00:00) in calendar,but it is not working for the other values.It is working for only first value.

Comment: what is `date` in `beforeShowDay: function (date) {`?

Comment: i have set the value from 26th mar to 6th may.......so date will take the value one by one (start from 26 to end on 6th)

Answer (score 0):

your code is like that

```
beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var ret = {};
        for(let date1 of active_dates1){
         if (date.getTime() === new Date(date1).getTime()) {
             ret = { classes: 'activeClass' };
             break;
         }
        }
      return ret;
    }
```